Does Remix share the same QueryClient between server and client for data caching using Tanstack React Query?
I'm working on a Remix application and trying to implement data caching using React Query's QueryClient. I want to ensure that both the server and client share the same instance of QueryClient to cache fetched data effectively.
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
     <HydrationBoundary state={dehydratedState}>
      {/* Other components */}
     </HydrationBoundary>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

I have the following setup in my root file to create a singleton QueryClient instance:
import { dehydrate, QueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";

let queryClientInstance: QueryClient | null = null;

const getQueryClient = () => {
  queryClientInstance = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
      queries: {
        staleTime: Infinity,
        refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
        gcTime: Infinity,
      },
    },
  });
  return queryClientInstance;
};

export const queryClient = getQueryClient();
export const dehydratedState = dehydrate(queryClient);


However, I’m experiencing an issue where it seems that new instances of QueryClient are being created every time the file is loaded, even though I expected to share the same instance across both server and client.

I expected to share the same instance across both server and client Not sure what you really mean here. Normally server and client runs on different computer altogether. How do you expect them to share an instance?

Basically, no. They are running in two completely separate systems. They could possibly share a "common serialized state", but that's about it.


I expected to share the same instance across both server and client.

That’s simply not how it works. The QueryClient is a JavaScript class, which you can’t send “over the wire”, so how can it be the same “instance” on the server and the client? It can’t.
What hydration does is it takes the content of the cache on the backend, then creates a new QueryClient it on the client, then puts the data from the server into it. It’s a new instance, but it will have the same data that was fetched on the server.

The other answers are correct, in that this is not how it really works, you can't send the QueryClient from the server to the client and you don't really want to do that.
Tanstack actually provides a remix example in their post about SSR: https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/guides/ssr
As a note, and you should not do this for this question, but you can pass stuff from the server to the client in remix by just returning it in the loader. So if you export it somewhere on the server, import it via a loader and return it, it will be accessible on the client. This wouldn't work for react-query but might be useful for other things.
